# Oracle queries executed in client side

Tags: java, oracle

Is it possible to find oracle queries executed in client side.

say , a sql request from jdbc client to oracle server . Will this communication be logged somewhere in temp location ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) to log the queries on client side.

I don't think it makes sense to log the communication itself, because the protocol used by oracle may not be publicly documented.